# Symfony Form Collection won't remove element

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Form Type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ......
            ->add('menores', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new CotizacionMenorType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required'  => false
            ))
            ......
    ;
}
```

Controller

```
public function editarAction(Cotizacion $cotizacion, Request $request)
{

    $pageData['accion'] = 'Editar';

    $objForm = $this->createForm(new EditarCotizacionType(), $cotizacion);

    $objForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($objForm->isValid()) {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($cotizacion->getMenores());
        die('</pre>');
        .............
    }
    .......
}
```

When I render the form and remove form the DOM 1 element, then I submit the form and the elements still in the coleccion., when I print de `$cotizacion->getMenores()` the removed element still there

Thanks

Comment: I added also the methods addMenor y removeMenor in Cotizacion class.

Answer (score 4):

In your relationship annotation, make sure you have orphanRemoval set.

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by a bug in version 2.3.10 https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10256, thanks A6 Software for the help.